# Stuff that will change on every page

Tags: html, footer

I would like to know that if there is a way that a certain piece of HTML code change on every page I create. In simple words for example, I make a HTML page called **1.html** and add a footer code. For example `<div class="footer">`, and I need to add this footer to every page I make. But then, I don't wanna add this footer code manually on every page since that would take time.

So making it more simple, I make **1.html**, **2.html** and **3.html** and make **footer.html** and add footer code to it. So instead of adding the actual footer code on every page, I add footer.html to **1.html**, **2.html** and **3.html** and then later edit footer.html that will update on **1.html**, **2.html** and **3.html**.

Hope you get my point.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that in plain HTML. You either have to use a scripting language (like Python, Ruby, PHP...), or a static website generator like [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) or [hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde).

If you are just writing static HTML files, I would go with the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server side language like PHP to do that

**1.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        Title 1
        <?php include('footer.html') ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        Title 2
        <?php include('footer.html') ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok so I can include the external footer through PHP right? And in the footer.html, I can paste my footer html code and include that PHP code in every page as I like and it will update the footer if I edit anything in footer.html?

Comment: That's correct. Including it that way, any change you do to your footer has to be done only on footer.html, and will affect the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

If your webserver supports it (many do), you could use [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

rough summary:

- change the extension on your html file to `.shtml`
- add this to your page wherever you want your footer to appear

  `<!--#include virtual="../path/to/footer.txt" -->`
- the footer file should only include the HTML fragment that you need to replace the SSI tag, so that when the tag is replaced with the footer you have a well-formed HTML page

In your [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/8qSiyNjV) your 'footer.txt' file should contain this:

```
<div class="footer">
  bla bla here....
</div>
```

And your .shtml file, in which you want the footer to appear, should look something like [this](http://pastebin.com/REQpRj3x)

(this assumes that your footer.txt file is in the same folder as the .shtml file)

Comment: Yeah It does. So if I just change the extension of my webpage from .html to .shtml, will it affect the html design?

Comment: No it won't affect the html design. Your shtml file should use normal well-formed html mark-up but you can add those include directives. It just tells the webserver to look for SS-includes in the page and replace them with the include files. This is the simplest way for you to achieve the result that you require.

Comment: when I add the include code to my .shtml page, the footer doesn't show up :(

Comment: see my expanded answer. The footer file should not be a fully-formed HTML page, it should only include the HTML fragment that you wish to replace the SSI tag. Also you must be sure the pathname is correct. The simplest way to test is to have the footer file in the same folder as your test shtml page so that the path is just the filename itself 'footer.txt'. If you want to include style sheet information in your footer you should tag the footer elements with CLASS or ID tags and set their styles in your main css stylesheet (the one that is used on the including page).

Comment: So my footer.txt contains just
` <div class="footer">
      bla bla here....
</div>
`

and my test.shtml file contains the stylesheet and the include, but still doesn't work...

Comment: look at my expanded expanded answer, does that help?

Comment: Ok so the problem was that my this host did not supported shtml. I tried the things you said on other host and it worked! :) Do you know any other way which doesn't use shtml?

Answer (score 1):

whether you use php or ssi remember that 'footer.html' must only be the code that would appear between the 'body' tags in a normal html page, or you will duplicate.